# Proving that the cosine is continous

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

$$|\cos(x) − \cos(y)| = 2 \cdot |\sin((x+y)/ 2)| \cdot |\sin ((x-y)/ 2)|.$$

How does this become

$$|\cos(x) − \cos(y)| <= 2 \cdot |\sin((y-x)/2)|$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\sin \theta| \leq 1$ for any real number $\theta$. Take $\theta=\frac {x+y} 2$.

To complete the proof of continuity use the fact that $sin z \to 0$ as $z \to 0$.